# Getting "undefined method for Nil Class" error when calling the reciprocal model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have two models `School` and `Course` where School `has_many` courses, and Course `belongs_to` school.  Additionally, School and Course are nested resources, where School is the parent resource, and Course the child.

I have created several test records in the Rails Console so that a query such as when the child calls upon the parent `Course.first.school` successfully executes and returns all the relevant information of the school `Course.first` is associated with.

However, when put into a controller function, I would instead get an error "undefined method `school' for nil:NilClass" for the following line:

`redirect_to school_course_path(@course.school, @course)`

.. as if the `.school` part wasn't recognized (where as it was in the console).  Why is this the case, and how do I get past this error?  Thanks!

Edit - as suggested, it could be that my @course instance variable isn't passed from method to method in the controller.  I have attempted at passing them through via a private method, but its still giving me the same error.  Here is my code (background: the model `Question` belongs_to `Course`, with `Course` having many questions.  Course *isn't* part of the nested routes)

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @course = Course.find(params[:course]) #confirmed working
    self.current_course = @course #I attempt to set current_course, a private method 
    @question = Question.new
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.new(params[:question]) #also works, in rails console all the questions confirms to have rails id
    if @question.save
      redirect_to school_course_path(current_course.school, current_course) #source of my frustrations - continues to returns same error message
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private 

  def current_course=(course)
    @current_school = course
  end


  def current_course
    @current_course
  end

end
```

Comment: Have you defined `@course` in the controller method?

Comment: `@course` successfully functions in the `new` method of the controller, so I assume since `create` is in the same controller, it should also be working.  On a side note, is there a way to check the value of an instance variable in a controller method that isn't linked to a view?

Comment: They have to be redefined in each method. That'd be your problem, I'd wager.

Comment: And I think your wager may be correct - I pasted the code to my controller in case it helps diagnose the problem...

Comment: Same issue, really: `current_course` isn't defined in your `create` method. See my answer for something that should work depending on your model relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work if your relationships are set up the way I think they are:

```
def create
  @question = Question.new(params[:question])
  @course = @question.course
  if @question.save
    redirect_to school_course_path(@course.school, @course)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have something like this in your create action:

```
@course = Course.new(params[:course])
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did use a `find` method to successfully identify the course via the `course_id`..but unfortunately its still throwing the exception.  I also pasted some additional code to the question body if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

your code is okay, it seems there is problem in your redirect.. redirect it to root_path and check whether it is working??

Comment: Happy to report that redirecting to root_path still works :).  Im still relatively unfamiliar with nested resources, but understand that here I just need to pass in something with `school_id` and `course_id` into the path.